# MySQL Query looking for 24 hrs of data only

Tags: mysql

I am trying to retrieve only the data for a 24 hr period.

The sql I have is:

```
SELECT * FROM aprstrack WHERE callsignSSID = 'VE9SC-9' AND
reporttime BETWEEN SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND SYSDATE()) ORDER BY
reporttime ASC
```

can someone tell me where I am going wrong. Thanks in-advance.

Comment: what seems to be the problem?

Comment: *what seems to be the problem, officer?

Comment: On a more serious note, are you sure reporttime is a datetime field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove extra brcket from `SYSDATE())`

```
SELECT * 
FROM aprstrack 
WHERE callsignSSID = 'VE9SC-9' 
        AND
reporttime BETWEEN (SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND SYSDATE() 
ORDER BY reporttime ASC
```

Comment: I believe it is needed to is it not to close the first one

Comment: then where is the first one? i think there isn't. i also updated the brackets

Comment: The first one is in front of the select $query = "(SELECT * FROM aprstrack WHERE callsignSSID = 'VE9SC-9' AND reporttime BETWEEN NOW()- INTERVAL '1' DAY AND NOW()) ORDER BY reporttime ASC";

Answer (score 2):

You have an unbalanced bracket,

```
SELECT * FROM aprstrack WHERE callsignSSID = 'VE9SC-9' AND
reporttime BETWEEN SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND SYSDATE() ORDER BY
reporttime ASC
```

Comment: The problem is i get all the data for the callsignSIID  VE9SC-9 what I want is just the data for the past day 24 hrs period.

Comment: $query = "(SELECT * FROM aprstrack WHERE callsignSSID = 'VE9SC-9' AND reporttime BETWEEN NOW()- INTERVAL '1' DAY AND NOW()) ORDER BY reporttime ASC";

Comment: Have you run SELECT * FROM aprstrack WHERE callsignSSID = 'VE9SC-9' AND reporttime < (SYSDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) to see, if the report times are correct?

Answer (score 1):

In standard SQL, you need to quote the number in that context.

```
reporttime BETWEEN SYSDATE() - INTERVAL '1' DAY AND ...
```

MySQL documentation suggests that you *don't* need to do that in MySQL. I'd be suspicious, and test. (I don't have a MySQL server instance running here, or I'd test it for you.)

You probably want NOW() instead of SYSDATE(). [SYSDATE() isn't deterministic](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_sysdate) within a single SQL statement, so it's possible (but unlikely) for the two calls to SYSDATE() to return different values.

Comment: I just tried : $query = "(SELECT * FROM aprstrack WHERE callsignSSID = 'VE9SC-9' AND reporttime BETWEEN NOW()- INTERVAL '1' DAY AND NOW()) ORDER BY
reporttime ASC"; That give me the same output.